# overloaded operator deduction using user-defined conversions in c++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

My problem may be related to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Call_to_an_overloaded_operator.
But in my case I have const complex types:

```
class Complex {
public:
   int data;

   Complex(int i) : data(i) {}
   bool operator < (const Complex& other) const { return data < other.data; }
};
class Holder {
public:
    Complex data;

    Holder(int i) : data(i) {}
    operator const Complex&() const { return data; }
};
//...
Holder a(1), b(2);
assert(a < b); //Error
```

Compiler error in g++ 4.9: `no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘Holder‘ and ‘Holder‘)`

Any idear how to fix this?

Btw. I need that conversion to only allow casts to const types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member comparison operators do not allow for implicit conversions on the left hand side, you need to make your operator a non-member function:

```
class Complex {
public:
   int data;

   Complex(int i) : data(i) {}
};

bool operator < (const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs) 
{ return lhs.data < rhs.data; }
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d9e5d0521fbf75f2)

Comment: is there no other way to allow member operators ?

Comment: Sure, you can explicitly cast the lhs every single time you want to use it as a `Complex`. The above approach is much more clear and maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

`a < b` is equivalent to `a.operator<(b)`.

`a` is of type `Holder` and doesn't have a function named `operator<`.

A function call to a member function doesn't trigger an implicit conversion from `Holder` to `Complex`.

If you cast `a` to `const Complex&` manually your function will work:

```
assert(((const Complex&)a) < b);
```